# VBA - IF statements with AND not working

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, user-controls

Any help would be great. I cant seem to get the ELSEIF with the AND to work.

I am using a user-form. When they press the button the user form appears with check boxes. I am having trouble when both check boxes are checked. individually they work fine,

I am not sure what i am doing wrong. any help would be greatly appreciated

```
If Intact.Value = True Then
    storDate = Sheets("escalation").Cells(Selection.Row, 2)
    storProject = Sheets("escalation").Cells(Selection.Row, 3)
    StorBill = Sheets("escalation").Cells(Selection.Row, 4)
    storIntact = "Intact"

    With objWord.ActiveDocument
    .formfields("text2").Result = storDate
    .formfields("Text3").Result = storProject
    .formfields("Text4").Result = StorBill
    .formfields("Text9").Result = storIntact
    End With

ElseIf Compugen.Value = True Then
    storDate = Sheets("escalation").Cells(Selection.Row, 2)
    storProject = Sheets("escalation").Cells(Selection.Row, 3)
    StorBill = Sheets("escalation").Cells(Selection.Row, 4)
    storCompugen = "Compugen"

    With objWord.ActiveDocument
    .formfields("text2").Result = storDate
    .formfields("Text3").Result = storProject
    .formfields("Text4").Result = StorBill
    .formfields("Text9").Result = storCompugen
    End With

ElseIf Intact.Value And Compugen.Value = True Then
    storDate = Sheets("escalation").Cells(Selection.Row, 2)
    storProject = Sheets("escalation").Cells(Selection.Row, 3)
    StorBill = Sheets("escalation").Cells(Selection.Row, 4)
    storIntact = "Intact"
    storDate1 = Sheets("escalation").Cells(Selection.Row, 2)
    storProject1 = Sheets("escalation").Cells(Selection.Row, 3)
    StorBill1 = Sheets("escalation").Cells(Selection.Row, 4)
    storCompugen = "Compugen"

    With objWord.ActiveDocument
    .formfields("text2").Result = storDate
    .formfields("Text3").Result = storProject
    .formfields("Text4").Result = StorBill
    .formfields("Text9").Result = storIntact
    .formfields("text5").Result = storDate1
    .formfields("Text6").Result = storProject1
    .formfields("Text7").Result = StorBill1
    .formfields("Text8").Result = storCompugen
    End With
End If
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't have `= True` next to Intact.Value in the line `ElseIf Intact.Value And Compugen.Value = True Then`

Comment: Much copy-pasta code in here. How about extracting a procedure to remove code duplication? (after you address the unreachable code issue)

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the order. Otherwise as soon as one condition is met the If clause is exited.

```
If Intact.Value And Compugen.Value Then
    'code
ElseIf Intact.Value Then
    'code
ElseIf Compugen.Value Then
    'code
End If
```

Comment: I'd just remove the explicit `= True` fluff - if `.Value` is a `Boolean`, then comparing it to `True` to make a Boolean expression is redundant.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - quite right, thanks, had missed in the latter two.

Comment: @YowE3K in that case isn't there some `CheckState` enum to test against (I might be mixing up UserForms and WinForms and WPF stuff)?

Comment: @Mat'sMug - Ahh - it appears to be `Null` if the checkbox is in the third state, so I guess it **will** only evaluate to `True` if it is checked.  I thought it returned -2 or something.  Forget I said anything.

Answer (score 1):

If `Intact.Value = True` is true then the first, not the third block will run.

Similarly if `Intact.Value = True` is not true and `Compugen.Value = True` is true, then the second block will run.

So you can see that the third block is not reachable.

The solution is to put the `Intact.Value = True And Compugen.Value = True` case first in the group.

Finally, `Foo.Value = True` is a tautology of the simpler `Foo.Value`. You can drop all the explicit `= True` comparisons.